# Best way to browse an mdf file from a local computer?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC site which will have a database. While I'm in this very early testing/concept phase I'm not hosting the database anywhere, just inside the local mdf file. What are some tools I can use to connect to the local test server so I can browse the tables and run test queries against the information in them without having to implement my own code/views? I'm interested in something like Sequel Pro for the Mac or phpmyadmin for linux (OS doesn't really matter since I'm working on a Mac developing inside a win 7 virtual machine).

Thanks!

(NOTE: I realize it is possible to get the table info dumped via Visual Studio, but it seems slow and not too useful... unless I'm missing a good way to use VS2010 the way I'd use one of the tools mentioned above?)

Comment: You've said `mdf file`, but tagged your question mysql, rather than sql-server or sql-server-express.... Are you sure it's MySql? =)

Comment: It is sql-server! Thanks :)... expresso needs to have more volume per shot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) to browse it, and do several other useful things as well, including table design and the like.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the built in tools right within Visual Studio. You'll need SQL Express installed, but you won't necessarily need Management Studio.

Go back to the Visual Studio installer (Repair or resintall features), and ensure that's selected as a feature.

- Open Server Explorer, and create a new Data Connection.
- Choose Microsoft SQL Server Database File
- find your .mdf
- Server Explorer then gives you a drill down of your Tables, Views, Stored Procedures, etc.